angular enteredview directive
I've been trying to create an angular directive which animates images with a shift-up-transition once they enter the viewport. However it's not working as expected.
I created a StackBlitz here

The main issue seems to be when the window is resized, then the directive seems to be triggered in the wrong way.
Also, in another demo-application I have a bootstrap navbar on the top, so actually the transition shouldn't start when the element enters the viewport, but 80px lower. How can I achieve this? I tried the IntersectionObserver's threshold but that's not working at all.
